# How to exclude select all checkbox row values from the result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I wanted to exclude the row values from the "select all" checkbox row in my datatable and preview all other values in a bootstrap modal with another datatable ,but how ?
This is my output for now:
[image]

This my original table heading coding and i am using a preview button with data-toggle to trigger the modal :

```
 <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" 
  onclick="toggle(this)"></th>

                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Product No</th>
                            <th>Serial No</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Categories</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Box No</th>
                            <th>Team</th>
                            <th>Registration</th>
                            <th>Latest Update</th>
                            <th>Action</th>


                        </tr>
                        </thead>
```

This is my javascript code to get row values from selected checkboxes and display them in the datatable,please help  :

```
//preview page
        $("#preview").on("click", function () {

            var result = $("tr:has(:checked)");
            if (result.length < 0) {
                alert("Please Select 2 to 4 Models");

            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }

            var json = result.map(function () {
                return [$(this).children().slice(1, 11).map(function () {
                    return $(this).text().trim()
                }).get()]
            }).get()

            var jsonString = (JSON.stringify(json, 0, "\t"));


            $.ajax(
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "preview_page.php",
                    data: {checkbox_value: jsonString},

                    success: function (data) {
                        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        console.log(result.length);
                        console.log(result[0][1]);

                        $('#preview_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e)
                        {
                            preview_table.clear();
                            for (var a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
                                var values=[result[a][0],result[a][1],result[a][2],result[a][3],result[a][4],
                                    result[a][5],result[a][6],result[a][7],result[a][8],result[a][9]];
                                   preview_table.row.add(values).draw();

                            }

                        })
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                        var msg = '';
                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                            msg = 'Time out error.';
                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                        } else {
                            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                        }
                        alert(msg);
                    }


                }
            )
        });
```

Comment: have you tried to start a=1 in this  for (var a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {?

Comment: but with this method, if i am not pressing select all, then the selected values will only starts from the second one,the first one will be ignored, am i right ?

Comment: cab you create example demo?